# How to check if a byte array Is a protobuf serialized byte array or normal byte array?

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

I recieved a byte array and *want to check if it's, or if it isn't, a protobuf serialized byte array*. How to do it? Does anyone have a good idea?
Thx!

Comment: What you want can't be done, sorry. At best, you can try parsing with the schema, and if it results in nonsense then you could *probably* say it's not protobuf. But that's assuming you have the schema for the expected protobuf you might get and also knowing what values make and don't make sense for it.

Comment: Why? You should already know, by your application protocol. If it isn't adequate to that, fix it so it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to de-serialize it; other than that there is no way to judge weather the array is proto byte array or not.

Comment: Note: some non-protobuf data will deserialize by chance. Not much, but it definitely isn't a 100% reliable approach.

Comment: So is there any development on this detection by google? For example, if the following bits occur at the beginning of the raw data (and/or ending of raw data), it is a proto message.